# Link two pictures pixels using Homography

Tags: c#, image, opencv, image-processing

I have two pictures that are the same but the second is distorted and have different dimensions. I want to be able to select a point on the first picture and find the exact same point on the second picture.
The synchronisation of the pictures will be made by 4 points on each picture.

Example:
Normal picture
[image]

Distorded picture
[image]

The result will be a function getting X,Y Point from first picture and returning X',Y' corresponding to the exact same Point on the second picture.

I foud OpenCV's findHomography() function which return a Homography matrix but in all the examples this matrix is used to distort the second image with warpPerspective() which is not what I want. I just want the corresponding coordinates / pixels between the two pictures.

Any tips on how to do that in C# ? (With OpenCV or not)

**EDIT :**

Points example :

Normal picture : [250, 25] , [250, 287] , [399, 287] , [400, 28]

Target picture : [0, 0] , [2098, 29538] , [19127, 28164] , [17097, -1200]

**EDIT USING OPEN CV :**

```
OpenCvSharp.Mat hCv = OpenCvSharp.Cv2.FindHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints);
OpenCvSharp.Point2d[] resultCv = OpenCvSharp.Cv2.PerspectiveTransform(targetCv, hCv);
```

Comment: Do you have the four corner points on both images?

Comment: Yes i have them.

Comment: Can you post those points for these images?

Comment: See: [Accord Framework .NET](http://accord-framework.net/), more specifically, the [Ransac Homography](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Imaging_RansacHomographyEstimator.htm). Also, [RANSAC & SIFT homography](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70434/ransac-sift-homography).

Comment: See my edit i added the points (some points are negative on the target because the first point is always 0,0)

Comment: If you have the Homography matrix, you can transform the set of points. That matrix is not only for images...

Comment: You will want to use the OpenCV function [`perspectiveTransform()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform). `warpPerspective` will warp an image, `perspectiveTransform` will warp an array of just points and give you the new locations. Alternatively you can compute this yourself with matrix multiplication easily, the formula is just to multiply the homogeneous coordinates and then scale---the formula is shown on the `perspectiveTransform` docs.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I used findHomography() to get the transformation matrix and then used perspectiveTransform() for [x:250, y:25] (which is one of my synchronisation point) of the first picture like the example in my edit but i don't get [0, 0] in output i'm getting something like [34, 145]. The four synchronisation points should be at the same coordinates, no ?

Comment: @Dairon if the homography you used matched point `A` with point `A'`, then applying the homography to point `A` should yield you point `A'`. In other words if the match `A: A'` was one of the pairs used to `findHomography()`, then `perspectiveTransform(A, homography) == A'` (or at least the two should be close).

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Unfortunally they are not matching, I don't think i'm doing something wrong see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander Reynolds comment, I finally used the [OpenCvSharp 3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU/) library.
You get the homography matrix using:

`homographyMatrix = OpenCvSharp.Cv2.FindHomography(originalPicturePoints, targetPicturePoints);`

and then to get any point on the target picture from the original picture:

`targetPoint = OpenCvSharp.Cv2.PerspectiveTransform(orignalPoint, homographyMatrix);`