# Map Projection Points to Real world Points

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, transformation, homography

I have searched far and wide for an answer to this problem, and I cannot find one so I am asking here.

**The Problem:**

I have a laser projecting down on a surface from overhead and I want to project some specific size shapes on this surface. In order to do this I need to 'calibrate' the laser to ground it in the real world.

The laser projects in its own coordinate system ranging from -32000 to 32000 in the x and y directions. I have targets setup on my surface in a rough rectangle (see image below for more details). The targets are set up in terms of millimeters and are their own coordinate system.

I need to be able to take points in millimeters and get them into this range of -32000 to 32000 accurately in an array of scenarios.

**Example:**

[image]

**What is the most accurate way of determining the laser space coordinates of the desired point?**

**Problem 2:**

The projection space is not guaranteed to be flat. It could be tilted in any direction. For example, if the bottom (in relation to the example picture) is raised, the real world coordinates stay the same in 2-D, but the measured laser coordinates become more of a Trapezoid. See Image below

[image]

If anyone has encountered/solved a similar problem or can even begin to point me in the right direction for a solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my post right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52480400/9130280

As an example I asked my question for pictures, because it was easier to explain but I applied the solution for device positioning on a surface. It is close to what you are trying to do.

Basically, you have to use [OpenCvSharp 3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU/) library (from nuget).

First you have to get a homography matrix. The only coordinates you have to know are the edges. So you fill up two arrays with the edges and then you use:

`homographyMatrix = OpenCvSharp.Cv2.FindHomography(originalPointsList, targetPointsList);`

And then to get any point in "millimeters" to its equivalent in laser coordinates:

`targetPoint = OpenCvSharp.Cv2.PerspectiveTransform(orignalPoint, homographyMatrix);`

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: This solution is exactly perfect for the question I asked. It turns out I didn't quite understand my problem when I began this problem. I marked your answer as correct because it is. But, I have started a new thread detailing my problem as I understand it now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615168/laser-projector-calibration-in-3d-space

Comment: Great! Let me know if you find any solution with your new thread. I could use it to improve my solution.